# Map kit framework in iphone

Tags: iphone, mapkit

I am using Map kit framework. I am creating travel guide app for iphone. In this I am having number of city and city having number of hotels. When I select any city then map will show city But when  I  Hotels and restaurants of city, map kit will not show searched hotels, restaurants It is only displays famous places..How to show hotels and restaurants.

Comment: please elaborate your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hii,

Mapkit is restricted to certain level,Better you can go for Google Places Search API -

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/

for Example - take a look at this

http://www.totagogo.com/2011/02/08/google-local-search-ios-code/

Example app - SCVNGR (using this Places API)

Please read Google Guidelines before using This

or Try to make use of Location based social networks API like foursquare etc.